# what are the Pros and cons of using default k8s scheduler for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I used spark on Bitnami (https://bitnami.com/stack/spark/helm) and I was able to port my current yarn application to this. This uses (or I think it uses) the default k8s scheduler to schedule the pods.

However, I see schedulers like yunikorn (https://yunikorn.apache.org) and volcano (volcano.sh) which say they provide schedulers for spark.

What I am not clear about is --the pros and cons of using k8s default scheduler for spark. I searched the web, but couldn't get an answer. What makes somebody not use k8s scheduler but use volcano.sh/ yunikorn? What use cases does k8s default scheduler not solve?

Comment: I don't tink the bitnami charts uses the k8s scheduler for spark.
It uses spark in standalone cluster mode, but it does not use spark on kubernetes. Pods are manually created by the helm charts for a spark master + some spark workers. Whereas spark on kubernetes would provision pod dynamically at  job submit: one pod for the driver and one pod for each executors.

Comment: yes in this context bitnami is useless. I finally endedup with spark operator + volcano

Answer (score 1):

Originally Spark used Yarn scheduler to manage the underlaying cluster and schedule jobs on top of it. In the last period YARN is replaced more and more ofter with Kubernetes that fits much better into cloud and distributed environments, usually based on containers, and overcome YARN in terms of containers management, multi-tenancy isolation, cluster elasticity, dependencies managements, flexibility to connect multi-cloud infrastructures, etc.

On the other side, probably, if you don't need to have multi-cloud configuration or if you don't have a containeraized application, YARN is a better choice.

In the meantime, other scheduler has come up, like Yunikorn. This scheduler can be seen as an higher layer of Kubernetes/Yarn schedulers, able to speak with both with a central management console.

```
      Yuvicorn
      /       \
    YARN  |   K8s
  -----------------
 one or more cluster
```

Yuvikorn scheduler collects resources from underneath resource management platforms (like YARN/K8s), and is responsible for container allocation requests. To give some usecase examples, you can use it if you need to manage a large cluster with multiple schedulers or if you have multiple resource managers to run on the same cluster and you need to handle those managers.

Comment: Thank you. But my question is more: Why not the default k8s scheduler? What's lacking in it is that volcano/ yunikorn is solving

Comment: Example: you have a large cluster with half java jobs and half container-based jobs. You can immagine to use YARN for the first and K8s for the latter. With Yuvicorn you can manage both. If you want to use K8s for java jobs you need to refactor their code and put them in containers and usually you loose a lot of containers benefits..

Comment: Yes it helps.  I wanted to know if the effort is worth it to try volcano vs stick with k8s scheduler. So asked the question. originally.

Comment: About Volcano, have a look of the CNCF page https://www.cncf.io/blog/2021/02/10/three-reasons-why-you-need-volcano/ and why Spark uses it https://www.cncf.io/blog/2022/06/30/why-spark-chooses-volcano-as-built-in-batch-scheduler-on-kubernetes/

Comment: For the record, the first scheduler for spark was Mesos and not Yarn.

Regarding the question: yunikorn is not another scheduler it is an extension of the kubernetes scheduler so that it can manage: priority, queues, gang-scheduling.

gang scheduling means you will not provision a driver pod without first making sure that the cluster has enough room to also provision executors.
Otherwise you may reach a state where the cluster is completely blocked because all resources are occupied by driver pods.